# removing 2 lines after doing a gsub

Tags: ruby

I have a file in which I need to replace 4 lines with 2 lines in specific spots the first line I can replace successfully with the following code. But, now that I have replaced the first line, how can I replace the next line with the text "//comment".. and delete the two lines after it?

For example:

```
String keyString = row.getKey();
// see Table T1002.
KeyParser keyParser;
keyParser.parseKey(keystr, key);
```

To:

```
Key& key = getKey();
//comment
```

Code so far:

```
text = File.read(filepath)
replace = text.gsub(/String keyString = row.getKey\(\);/, 'Key& key = getKey();')
File.open(filepath, "w") {|file| file.puts replace}
```

PS: Also how can I specify the search string without having to escape my parenthesis

Comment: You can use `gsub!` to do an in-place modification instead of creating a temporary variable `replace`.

Comment: do you know how I can do the gsub without escaping my parenthesis?

Comment: `(` and `)` are always special in a standard regular expression. That's just the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
text.gsub(/String keyString = row\.getKey\(\);\s+\/\/.*?[\n\r](.*?[\n\r]){2}/, "Key& key = getKey();\n// comment")
```

The regex `(.*?[\n\r]){2}` means two lines. And `\s+\/\/.*?[\n\r]` for the line that holds the current comment.

Comment: Damn, it's deleting three lines instead of two.. I changed the regex slightly though to: /String keyString = row\.getKey\(\);\s+.*?[\n\r](.*?[\n\r]){2}/, "Key& key = getKey();\n// comment"